# Error: bad operand types for binary operator '+'

Tags: java, concatenation

I have here a code that would take a String called `toRepeat` and repeat it in the same line by n number of times. For example toRepeat = *, n= 3, result = ***

```
public class RepeatIt {
    public static String repeatString(final Object toRepeat, final int n) {
        int i = 0;
        if (toRepeat instanceof String) {
            while (i < n) {
                toRepeat = toRepeat + toRepeat;
            }
            return toRepeat;
        } else {
            return "Not a string";
        }
    }
}
```

However I get an Error on the `+` sign between the 2 `toRepeat` which states bad operand types for binary operator `+`. If you know how I could fix this please tell me I would much appreciate it.

Comment: you should use downcasting

Comment: When is your loop supposed to do?  You never change `i` or `n` so your while loop will repeat forever.

Comment: Another alternative is using String `concat` method instead of `+` operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change

```
while (i < n){
    toRepeat = toRepeat + toRepeat; // operations are not defined for type Object
}
return toRepeat;
```

to

```
String tr = (String)toRepeat; // cast to String 
while (i < n){
    tr = tr + tr; // valid on String
    i++; // some condition to terminate
}
return tr;
```

---

***Edit***: As suggested by @oleg, using `StringBuilder` should be preferred over concatenating Strings in a loop.

---

***Edit2***: To increment one character at a time, you can do something like :

```
String tr = (String)toRepeat; // this would be *
String finalVal = ""; 
while (i < n){
    final = finalVal + tr; // would add * for each iteration
    i++; 
}
return finalVal;
```

Comment: A for loop might be easier.

Comment: **Do Not Use It!!!** This is a **BIG** mistake. Do not concatenate string within loop. Each loop iteration build a **new string**. As result in the string pool you get n different string objects!! If you have to do it in the loop, then **StringBuilder** is your friend.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik Agreed, but the solution was not to address the performance impact there initially, made an edit to address that. Thanks.

Comment: @CWilliams If that helped, do accept it as an answer to let it be useful for future readers as well.

Comment: I alredy did but im facing another problem now as stated by another answer if I were to increment i ++ the result would equal to ** after the 1st loop, **** after the second loop ******** by the third and so on and Im trying to find a solution to that now

Comment: @CWilliams good note, but I think that this obvious situation and developers should not even think about string concatenation with loop. I believe that we have enough problem in other code parts. :-)

Comment: @CWilliams maybe my example in another anwer for this question using Apache lib for String could be useful for you? I use it very often.

Comment: It could be but I' started doing java like a week ago and I don't think I understand your code complitly right now. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are actually three errors here:
The first is the type `Object` of `toRepeat` (and it being `final`, i.e. you may not assign a new value): there is no `+` for Object. You can cast it to `String` as shown in the answer before.
Second: your loop does not terminate, because `i` stays `0`.
Third: If you increment `i` (e.g. `i += 1` in the loop). You will get `**` after the first loop, `****` after the second and 8 stars after the third loop.

Comment: So I fixed the other problems but the i one how can I increment i to go up by only 1 value

Comment: Do not replace the string with a concatenation like tr+tr but concat the original value: tr + toRepeat.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Apache lib could help in most cases. It contains `StringUtils` class with lots of useful method to work with `String`. This is one of them:

```
public class RepeatIt {
    public static String repeatString(final Object toRepeat, final int n) {
        return toRepeat instanceof String ? org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.repeat((String)toRepeat, n) : "Not a string";
    }
}
```